# How to compare two str values dataframe python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I am trying to compare two different values in a dataframe. The questions/answers I've found I wasn't able to utilize.

```py
import pandas as pd
# from datetime import timedelta

"""
read csv file
clean date column
convert date str to datetime
sort for equity options
replace date str column with datetime column
"""
trade_reader = pd.read_csv('TastyTrades.csv')
trade_reader['Date'] = trade_reader['Date'].replace({'T': ' ', '-0500': ''}, regex=True)
date_converter = pd.to_datetime(trade_reader['Date'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
options_frame = trade_reader.loc[(trade_reader['Instrument Type'] == 'Equity Option')]
clean_frame = options_frame.replace(to_replace=['Date'], value='date_converter')

# Separate opening transaction from closing transactions, combine frames
opens = clean_frame[clean_frame['Action'].isin(['BUY_TO_OPEN', 'SELL_TO_OPEN'])]
closes = clean_frame[clean_frame['Action'].isin(['BUY_TO_CLOSE', 'SELL_TO_CLOSE'])]
open_close_set = set(opens['Symbol']) & set(closes['Symbol'])
open_close_frame = clean_frame[clean_frame['Symbol'].isin(open_close_set)]

'''
convert Value to float
sort for trade readability
write
'''
ocf_float = open_close_frame['Value'].astype(float)
ocf_sorted = open_close_frame.sort_values(by=['Date', 'Call or Put'], ascending=True)
# for readability, revert back to ocf_sorted below
ocf_list = ocf_sorted.drop(
    ['Type', 'Instrument Type', 'Description', 'Quantity', 'Average Price', 'Commissions', 'Fees', 'Multiplier'], axis=1
    )
ocf_list.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
ocf_list['Strategy'] = ''
# ocf_list.to_csv('Sorted.csv')

# create strategy list
debit_single = []
debit_vertical = []
debit_calendar = []
credit_vertical = []
iron_condor = []

# shift columns
ocf_list['Symbol Shift'] = ocf_list['Underlying Symbol'].shift(1)
ocf_list['Symbol Check'] = ocf_list['Underlying Symbol'] == ocf_list['Symbol Shift']

# compare symbols, append depending on criteria met
for row in ocf_list:
    if row['Symbol Shift'] is row['Underlying Symbol']:
        debit_vertical.append(row)

print(type(ocf_list['Underlying Symbol']))
ocf_list.to_csv('Sorted.csv')
print(debit_vertical)
# delta = timedelta(seconds=10)
```

The error I get is:

```
line 51, in <module>
    if row['Symbol Check'][-1] is row['Underlying Symbol'][-1]:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I am trying to compare the newly created shifted column to the original, and if they are the same, append to a list. Is there a way to compare two string values at all in python? I've tried checking if Symbol Check is true and it still returns an error about `str` indices must be `int`. `.iterrows()` didn't work

Comment: What makes you think the issue is with comparing strings? The code in the error message isn't part of what you shared, by the way. You can almost certainly replace the `for row in ocf_list:` loop with a simply use of `.loc[]`. Why use `is` in `if row['Symbol Shift'] is row['Underlying Symbol']:` ?

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question would be easier to answer if the example you provided was stripped down to the simplest chunk possible that produced the same error (often referred to as an [MVC example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing. Sorry.

Comment: Okay I see what's going on, that was a previous attempt to show that I've tried different things. It's still the same error, which includes the word string, so I figured it involved string. No matter how I phrase the logic, it comes back about string or str. I guess I have a lot farther to go if I'm getting something that basic that wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you will actually iterate through the columns of your DataFrame, not the rows:

```
for row in ocf_list:
    if row['Symbol Shift'] is row['Underlying Symbol']:
        debit_vertical.append(row)
```

You can use one of the methods `iterrows` or `itertuples` to iterate through the rows, but they return rows as lists and tuples respectively, which means you can't index them using the column names, as you did here.

Second, you should use `==` instead of `is` since you are probably comparing values, not identities.

Lastly, I would skip iterating over the rows entirely, as pandas is made for selecting rows based on a condition. You should be able to replace the aforementioned code with this:

```
debit_vertical = ocf_list[ocf_list['Symbol Shift'] == ocf_list['Underlying Symbol']].values.tolist()
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to do `ocf_list[ocf_list...]` ?

Comment: The expression within the brackets is a selector - a condition that determines which rows to select from the DataFrame. Hence, each row in `ofc_list` for which `ocf_list['Symbol Shift'] == ocf_list['Underlying Symbol']` is true, will be selected.